# Issue on saving multiple meta fields value as array in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I make custom fields with same name, in meta fields I restore the values from DB and want to save them as a serialize in my pattern.

Like this:

```
Array
(
    [job] => 'sdfsdf'
    [image] => Array
        (
            [attachment_id] => '2121' 
            [url] => 'http://siteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/image.jpg'
        )

    [popup_text] => 'A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
)
```

But when I save the values, all values restore as empty.

Now here is my meta fields code:

```
global $wpdb;

    $dsl_fw_options = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dsl_fw_options', true);

    $dsl_staff_qry = $wpdb->get_row("Select * From ". $wpdb->posts . " Where ID = ".$post->ID);

    $dsl_staff_parent = $wpdb->get_row("Select * From ". $wpdb->posts . " Where post_parent = " . $post->ID . " And post_type = 'attachment' And (post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg' Or post_mime_type = 'image/png')");

?>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                <strong>Job Title</strong>
            </td>
            <td width="80%">
                <input type="text" name="dsl_txt_fw_options['job']" value="<?php echo $dsl_fw_options['job'] ?>" style="width: 50%;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="dsl_txt_fw_options['attachment_id']" value="<?php echo $dsl_staff_parent->ID; ?>" style="width: 50%;">
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="dsl_txt_fw_options['url']" value="<?php echo $dsl_staff_parent->guid; ?>" style="width: 50%;">
                <br>
                <textarea name="dsl_txt_fw_options['popup_text']"><?php echo $dsl_staff_qry->post_content; ?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I get values from DB as per required and it shows perfectly.

And here is my update meta values code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'dr_save_staff_post');
function dr_save_staff_post() {
    global $post;

    $dsl_arr = array();

    $dsl_arr_val = $_POST['dsl_txt_fw_options'];

    foreach ($dsl_arr_val as $dsl_key => $dsl_val) {
        $dsl_arr['job'] = $dsl_val->job;
        $dsl_arr['image'] = array(
                                'attachment_id' => $dsl_val->attachment_id,
                                'url' => $dsl_val->url
                            );
        $dsl_arr['popup_text'] = $dsl_val->popup_text;
    }

    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'fw_options', $dsl_arr);
}
```

When I save these values and check the values from DB it gives me that result:

```
a:3:{s:3:"job";N;s:5:"image";a:2:{s:13:"attachment_id";N;s:3:"url";N;}s:10:"popup_text";N;}
```

I don't know where am I doing wrong, so please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all change the name of each input type. like

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                <strong>Job Title</strong>
            </td>
            <td width="80%">
                <input type="text" name="dsl_txt_fw_job" value="<?php echo $dsl_fw_options['job ?>" style="width: 50%;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="dsl_txt_fw_attachment_id" value="<?php echo $dsl_staff_parent->ID; ?>" style="width: 50%;">
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="dsl_txt_fw_url" value="<?php echo $dsl_staff_parent->guid; ?>" style="width: 50%;">
                <br>
                <textarea name="dsl_txt_fw_popup_text"><?php echo $dsl_staff_qry->post_content; ?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then get these values like

```
$dsl_val_job = $_POST['dsl_txt_fw_job'];

$dsl_val_attachment_id = $_POST['dsl_txt_fw_attachment_id'];

$dsl_val_url = $_POST['dsl_txt_fw_url'];

$dsl_val_popup_text = $_POST['dsl_txt_fw_popup_text'];
```

After this you can convert this values to an array in which format you want. Like

```
$dsl_val['job'] = $dsl_val_job;

$dsl_val['image'] = array ( 'attachment_id' => $dsl_val_attachment_id, 

                             'url'=>  $dsl_val_url );

$dsl_val['popup_text'] = $dsl_val_popup_text;
```

That's it. :-)